# VBA loop issue when trying to append a large amount of rows from Excel to Access

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying all day to figure this out. I'm hoping that I'm just missing something simple. 
Background...
I have an Excel worksheet with 6 columns and 258 rows. I need the user to be able to press a button and append all of that data to a table in Access. I am able to do it for one row of data, but I'm having trouble getting multiple rows.

Everything works up to the For Loop. It does loop through all the columns, but when it gets to the 7th one it throws an error. It should loop 6 times then go to the next row. The error that I'm getting is Run-time error 3265, Item not found in this collection. I'm guessing that's because there aren't 7 columns. What am I missing?

```
Sub ExportResponses()
Dim oSelect As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer

Worksheets("Responses").Activate
```

'this is currently asking to verify the range, but I'd like to just code it since it will always be the same.
    Set oSelect = Application.InputBox("Range", , Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, , , , , 8)

```
Dim oDAO As DAO.DBEngine
Dim oWS As DAO.Workspace
Dim oDB As DAO.Database
Dim oRS As DAO.Recordset

ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set oDAO = New DAO.DBEngine
Set oWS = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set oDB = oWS.OpenDatabase("T:\Databases\QA Database\QA Data.accdb")
Set oRS = oDB.OpenRecordset("tblResponses_Temp")

For i = 2 To oSelect.Rows.Count
    oRS.AddNew
    For j = 1 To oSelect.Columns.Count
        oRS.Fields(j) = oSelect.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    oRS.Update
Next I

oDB.Close
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you add a statement `Debug.Print oSelect.Columns.Count`, is it 6 or 7? Don't you need to add some code to ensure that the user selected range does not exceed 6 columns? It is pretty clear that the error is due to `oRS.Fields(7)` does not exist.

Comment: I added the debug statement and I get 6. It fails after that. It will never have more than 6 columns

Comment: I think the `Fields` collection is zero-based so try `oRS.Fields(j - 1)` instead of `oRS.Fields(j)`

Comment: ah @barrowc I'm sure you nailed it! It **is** zero-based. Should be posted as answer.

Comment: That worked!!! It appended all 258 rows as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The `Fields` collection is zero-based so try `oRS.Fields(j - 1)` instead of `oRS.Fields(j)`

The six fields you have are referred to via `Fields(0)` through `Fields(5)`. Attempting to access `Fields(6)` will cause an error